# How to get configuration of all azure vm instances using API or python package

Tags: python, azure, google-api-python-client

I have to use API or python package which will provide me information of all Azure vm instances
means all instance types those are present in the azure.

First, installed the Azure Python SDK using pip:

`pip install azure-sdk`

Next, import the necessary modules and authenticate with Azure:

`import os` 
`from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials`
`from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient`
`subscription_id = 'my-subscription-id'`

`client_id = 'my-client-id'` client_secret = 'my-client-secret' tenant_id = 'my-tenant-id'`

`credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials( client_id=client_id, secret=client_secret, tenant=tenant_id )`
`vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()`

`for vm in vm_list:`
`print(vm.name)`

Using above code, I could see only those instances which I have created in my subscription ,
But I want All the instance types and its information using any API or python package.

Comment: What's with the seemingly random "`your text`"s in your post body?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all Azure Virtual Machines, you should probably use the Resource Graph.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/first-query-python#run-your-first-resource-graph-query

It will allow you to get all instances, for any subscription your service principal has access.

The Resource Graph request should be something like
Resources | where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'

Comment: Right, this is the way to go for getting all Azure VMs.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

*I tried in PowerShell to get list of all virtual machine Instance across all subscription.*

**Command:**

```
$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription 
foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) 
{
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name | Set-AzContext 
az account set -s $sub.Name     
write-host "subscriptionname :" $sub.Name  
write-host " " 
$vmlist=Get-AzVM 
$vmlist
}
```

**Console:**
[image]

*If you need specific view (virtual machine name or any other properties) of azure virtual machine, you can use below command.*

**Command:**

```
$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription 
foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) 
{
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name | Set-AzContext 
az account set -s $sub.Name     
write-host "subscriptionname :" $sub.Name   
write-host " "
$vmlist=Get-AzVM 
write-host "Vm  from  subscription " $sub.Name 

foreach ($vm in $vmlist) 
{
write-host "vm name :   " $vm.name
}
write-host " " 
}
```

**Console:**
[image]

If you need to call PowerShell script from python you can refer this [link](https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/executing-powershell-from-python/) by Jamie.